# start and stop EC2 instances based on a schedule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can I start or stop EC2 instances based on a schedule (night, weekend)? are AWS EC2 API only solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

AWS does not have any built-in method to schedule instances to start or stop. You have a few options:

1. Run your own EC2 instance that used `cron` or Task Manager to run your own scripts using the AWS SDK/CLI to start and stop the instances.
2. Use scheduled Auto Scaling to terminate and re-launch EC2 instances for you.
3. Use AWS Lambda to execute a Lambda function that starts and stops your instances, using the Lambda scheduler to schedule the execution of your Lambda function.
4. Use a third-party service that will start and stop your EC2 instances for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my software, CloudRoboAWSScheduler. Download it from http://cloudrobo.net/download/

Please go through the setup details mentioned in http://cloudrobo.net/setup/

It is absolutely free. 
Features: 
- Easy to use GUI 
- START / STOP EC2 Instances 
- Reduce costs by starting and stopping your EC2 instances automatically 
- Create dynamic schedules using ClouRobo AWS scheduler 
- Manage multiple accounts in different AWS regions - Easy to use user interface 
- Installs on Windows Server 2008/2012 or Windows 7/8/10

Note: This is a beta release.

-Viswanath